# PHP Curl code to urlfetch in python - need help

Tags: python, google-app-engine, curl, urlfetch

This is my PHP Code with Curl .  I need to do the same function using urlfetch in GAE Python. How can pass all these parameter to urlfetch. Please help me.

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    $timeout = 30;

// Logining to my TNT 
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://my.tnt.com/myTNT/login/LoginInitial.do?cmd=1&navigation=1");
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "userid=aaaa@bb.com&password=1234qwe");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "userid=; password=; JSESSIONID=E1FC9A6D18002370BD4AF7DDBBA617A0; BIGipServermy_tnt_com_pool=2636720036.20480.0000");
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 20);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1");
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://my.tnt.com/myTNT/login/LoginInitial.do");
    $text = curl_exec($curl);
    $pos = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

This is my python Code.

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
import urllib

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
     url = "https://my.tnt.com/myTNT/login/LoginInitial.do?cmd=1&navigation=1"
     form_fields = {
         "userid": "aaaa@bb.com",
         "password": "1234qwe",
     }
     form_data = urllib.urlencode(form_fields)
     result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url,
                    payload=form_data,                        
                    method=urlfetch.POST,
                    validate_certificate='TRUE',
                    headers={'Host': 'my.tnt.com',
                                    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                                    'Accept-Language': 'en-us,en;q=0.5',
                                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                                    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
                                    'Keep-Alive': '115',
                                    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                                    'Referer': 'https://my.tnt.com/myTNT/login/LoginInitial.do',
                                    'Cookie': 'userid=; password=; JSESSIONID=E1FC9A6D18002370BD4AF7DDBBA617A0; BIGipServermy_tnt_com_pool=2636720036.20480.0000',
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                    'Content-Length': '45',
                                   }
                      )
    self.response.out.write(result.final_url)
```

I'm trying to access the MyTNT webpage. So first i need to login to that page. Above code is for logging into the mytnt website. When i run the PHP Code, it will redirecting to the mytnt home page (https://my.tnt.com/myTNT/landing/landingPage.do). 
But When i run the python file it was redirecting to the same login page. The Login was unsuccessful when i execute the python file using urlfetch.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far, and ask about how to convert any particular parameters you're unsure about - don't expect us to do the work for you.

Comment: @Nick Sorry. I forgot to add the py code. Now i updated.

Comment: Your explanation of what's wrong with it leaves something to be desired. What does "it is still pointing the login page" mean?

Comment: I'm trying to access the MyTNT webpage. So first i need to login to that page. Above code is for logging into the mytnt website. When i run the PHP Code, it will redirecting to the mytnt home page (https://my.tnt.com/myTNT/landing/landingPage.do). But When i run the python file it was redirecting to the same login page. The Login was unsuccessful when i execute the python file using urlfetch.

Comment: You need to turn on debugging and see what the PHP and the Python are *actually* doing.

Comment: How do i debug the urlfetch function in Gae Python  ?

Comment: The obvious first step would be to return the body of the response, which presumably has an error message indicating why your signin didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your php code is using a "cookie jar" like what is available in the [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) library.

I've used mechanize before for basic scraping of websites, but not actually to log in, so I can't say 100% that it will work for you but I think it's your best shot.

Comment: I have Download the Package (http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/mechanize/mechanize-0.2.5.zip) and Copy the mechanize folder to my gae folder. And Try to import. But getting error :     
fp.fileno = lambda: None
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fileno'

Comment: While it's true he'll need to preserve cookies, that's not his immediate issue. Also, I'm not positive Mechanize works on App Engine.

Comment: Mechanize does indeed work on GAE, however I can't say with certainty whether the "cookie jar" aspect works.